# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'set_property' Tkinter, GStreamer python3

Tags: tkinter, gstreamer

I'm trying to make a video player with tkinter, GStreamer and python3, and i have the following code

```
import sys, os
from tkinter import *
from gi.repository import GObject
from gi.repository import GLib
from gi.repository import Gtk
from gi.repository import Gst
def start():
        player.set_property('video-sink', None)
        player.set_property("uri", "./video.avi")
        player.set_state(Gst.STATE_PLAYING)

def on_sync_message(bus, message):
        if message.structure is None:
                return
        message_name = message.structure.get_name()
        if message_name == "prepare-xwindow-id":
                imagesink = message.src
                imagesink.set_property("force-aspect-ratio", True)
                imagesink.set_xwindow_id(mwin_id)

window = Tk()
window.geometry("500x400")
movie_window = Frame(window,bg='#000000')
movie_window.pack(side=BOTTOM,anchor=S,expand=YES,fill=BOTH)

mwin_id = movie_window.winfo_id()

player = Gst.ElementFactory.make("playbin2", "player")
fakesink = Gst.ElementFactory.make("fakesink", "fakesink")
player.set_property("video-sink", fakesink)


bus = player.get_bus()
bus.add_signal_watch()
bus.enable_sync_message_emission()
bus.connect("sync-message::element", on_sync_message)


window.mainloop()
start()
```

but I receive an error:

```
(reproductor4.py:6856): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_element_factory_make: assertion `gst_is_initialized ()' failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "reproductor4.py", line 30, in <module>
    player.set_property("video-sink", fakesink)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'set_property'
```

Some ideas of why this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution was this lines:
Finally only appends this lines before to call :
GObject.threads_init()
Gst.init(None)

Answer (score 0):

Line 30 is `player.set_property("video-sink", fakesink)`.  The Traceback and Attribute error message appear to be claiming that `player` is None.  Test that with `print(player)` before that line.  However, I do not understand the extra message before `Traceback`.  It suggests that an assertion within the gst code failed.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is actually:

```
(reproductor4.py:6856): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_element_factory_make: assertion `gst_is_initialized ()' failed
```

Nothing in your code is calling the initialization routine: gst_init() (it likely is Gst.init() in python). Without the initialization gstreamer won't work.

Comment: thank you very much finally I had to initialize the object and only had append:
GObject.threads_init () 
Gst.init (None)

Answer (score 0):

this is due to memory error..
try:

```
export GST_LIBS="-lgstreamer-1.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0"
export GST_CFLAGS="-pthread -I/usr/include/gstreamer-1.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include"
```

and it will run for sure..